# MVVM ListBox - changing the background of an item based on its index

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox that represents the lines of text in a scripting language. I need to "single-step" the script, highlighting the current script line (say with a green background).

The modelview has a "CurrentLine" property that is the index of the current line so I figured I would write a trigger on the ItemContainerStyle and use a converter to figure out if the index of the list box item is the same as the CurrentLine. But I'm struggling to pass in the current line value to the converter as it comes from the VM, and I can't pass non-constant values into the converter as parameters. Neither can I do so with the "Value" of the trigger. How can I pass these values in?

Comment: Is it mandatory to store the index in the VM or could you save the current line as the same type as the objects in your Lines collection?

Comment: At the moment, the Lines collection is List<string>. I suppose I could write

    `class Line
    {
      string text;
      bool isCurrent;
    }`

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @JulianGold no I think what he means is to have your `CurrentLine` property of type `string`. Thus in your `ListBoxItem` style just check if `CurrentLine` matches the `{Binding .}` for that very item and you got your match.

Comment: @Viv there may be several script lines that match identically?

Comment: That's what I meant. If your collection of Lines is a, say, ObservableCollection<string>, then you could make CurrentLine a string, rather than an integer.

Comment: @JulianGold: It's probably a good idea to save the lines as some custom objects (reference type) rather than strings (value types) to allow proper check for equality.

Comment: @JulianGold I've added an alternative approach to my answer, using an integer index. Now, you can choose ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CURRENTLINE EXPOSED AS REFERENCE TYPE**

To modify the ViewModel to save the current line as an actual `LineViewModel` (or whatever, depending on how your VM exposes the Lines), rather than the selected index is much cleaner solution in my opinion.

Then you can define the trigger using a multibinding with a converter that checks for equality:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" x:Name="List">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <sample:EqualityConverter x:Key="Converter" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentLine" ElementName="List" />
                            <Binding />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

And the converter:

```
public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0] == values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

That's it.

**CURRENTLINE EXPOSED AS STRING (VALUE TYPE)**

If you still want to use an integer index, you can uitilize the `AlternationIndex`. You set the `AlternationCount` of the list to the number of its items, which ensures that every item has its unique index and then bind to the attached property `ItemsSource.AlternationIndex` of the ListBoxItem. This way, you won't mix up lines with the same content.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Resources}" x:Name="List" AlternationCount="{Binding Resources.Count}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <sample:EqualityConverter x:Key="Converter" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentItem" ElementName="List"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

You need to modify the converter slightly:

```
public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Equals(values[1], values[0] );
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this still work if there are several identical script lines?

Comment: @JulianGold: No, you would need to wrap the lines in some custom objects, then it would work.

Comment: Thanks Marc - a nice bit of Pixie Dust there :-)